# Sending an email of the contents inside a text file

Tags: python, file, email, smtp

In Python, how would I send an email with the contents of a text file? I have a text file named "example.txt" that contains some plain string data. I'm attempting to use Python to develop a code that will send those contents via email. I don't want to attach the file; instead, I want to send the content as the email's body. I would be grateful if someone could assist me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure which module you are using for smtp, but I found this tutorial called [Sending Emails with Python](https://realpython.com/python-send-email/) by RealPython.com. Check it out if you are using smtplib.

To solve your issue of wanting to read the text file’s contents, instead of attaching a file, I wrote a script to read the contents of a textfile and put it into a list, which I proceeded to turn into one string (because smtplib wants a string for the email message and not a list):

```
with open(“example.txt”, “r”) as textfile:
    content = textfile.readlines()
    email_body = “”.join(content) # new line characters will be included
    textfile.close()
```

If you want to keep it as a list, just erase the line with `email_body`.

In the tutorial I linked above, it says to [send a plain text email](https://realpython.com/python-send-email/#sending-your-plain-text-email) by adding the following, to your script:

**The code below is copied from the tutorial, do not add this next code sample to your script:**

```
# Don’t add this script - it’s an example
sender_email = "my@gmail.com"
receiver_email = "your@gmail.com"
message = """\
Subject: Hi there

This message is sent from Python."""

server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

So we would just replace `message` with our `email_body` string:

**This is a modified version of the example. Only use this version of the code:**

```
sender_email = "my@gmail.com"
receiver_email = "your@gmail.com"
# remove message and replace it with email_body
server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, email_body)
```

Side Note: the tutorial mentions using 2 new line characters for the email subject. That’s important to keep in mind if you want to include an email subject in your text file. See the link above for details.

For example:

```
Subject: LOREM IPSUM

Lorem ipsum. this is the email body.
Notice how there is a space in between the subject line and the email body. 
The subject line and the body are separated by two, new line characters.
```

To double check that the text in example.txt was correctly extracted, print out `email_body’ before you try to send the email. If your subject line was correct, you should see something similar to this:

```
Subject: LOREM IPSUM\n\nLorem ipsum is the email body.\n Notice how there is a space in between the subject line and the email body.\nThe subject line and the body are separated by two, new line characters.\n
```

Notice how there are two \n (new line characters) after the subject line. `Subject: LOREM IPSUM\n\n`

Hopefully that works out for you. It seemed to work on the debug server when I tried it.

Comment: I just wanted to ask, this email sends 2 email, the one with my file contents does not have a subject, how do I add subject to my email?

Comment: I edited the original post for you, hopefully it helps answer your questions better now